# Load previous values in multiChoiceItems Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alertDialog which prompts user to make multiple Choices, I am able to make few selections and save selected items in arrayList but when I fire that alertBox again, it gets reset and all the checkboxes are unChecked, I want them to retain the state I left them at until I reset them manually. How does this work? 
My code:

```
ArrayList<String> participants = db.getNames();
            final String[] arr = participants.toArray(new String[participants
                    .size()]);
            boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[participants.size()];
            final ArrayList<String> selectedParticipants = new ArrayList<String>();

            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            b.setTitle("Select the participants:");
            b.setMultiChoiceItems(arr, checkedItems,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            if (isChecked) {

                                selectedParticipants.add(arr[which].toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
            b.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(EnterExpense.this,
                            "" + selectedParticipants, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You can store them in a SharedPreferences file also. If you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your above code is correct only, but only one thing you missed is to update your checked items inside  `boolean [] checkedItems` array list. Once user selects all the participants get the selected participants positions and add true for all those postions into the `chekedItems` list and remaining items make it as a false once you are done it will definitely work !!.

You could use `getCheckedItemIds()` or `getCheckedItemPositions ()` to get a list of checked items from the listview. You should use `AlertDialog.getListView()` to get the dialog's listview first.

```
b.getListView().getCheckedItemPositions ();
```

Comment: can you explain that with code? I've used this method first time and can't figure out how to do what you've told.

Comment: have you tried same what i have mentioned ?? if not try first and if you finds any issues then let me know !!

Comment: getListVIew method is undefined for this dialog.